# Upload file from jenkins to S3 bucket

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3

Is any one know how to upload files from jenkins to amazon S3 bucket.
I am trying to do the same by adding

> S3 publisher plugging

and using

> Amazon s3 profile

but if fails to upload the file and gives following error

> ERROR: Failed to upload files java.io.IOException: Expecting Ant GLOB
>   pattern, but saw
>   '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Narad-dev-Clean/workspace/*_audit.csv'. See
>   http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html for syntax    at
>   hudson.FilePath.glob(FilePath.java:1766)  at
>   hudson.FilePath.access$1700(FilePath.java:195)    at
>   hudson.FilePath$32.invoke(FilePath.java:1747)     at
>   hudson.FilePath$32.invoke(FilePath.java:1744)     at
>   hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1018)   at
>   hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:996)    at
>   hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1744)  at
>   hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1729)  at
>   hudson.plugins.s3.S3BucketPublisher.perform(S3BucketPublisher.java:175)
>     at
>   hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
>     at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$2.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:32)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
>     at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)  at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:665)
>     at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1745)  at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)   at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404) Build step 'Publish
>   artifacts to S3 Bucket' changed build result to UNSTABLE Finished:
>   UNSTABLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jenkins there is no need to give the complete path of your file like

> /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Narad-dev-Clean/workspace/*_audit.csv'.

just give file name and it will automatically take it from there default location like

> *_audit.csv (or file name what ever it is)